# Pandas guess delimiter with sep=None

Tags: python, csv, pandas

[Pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/io.html#io-read-csv-table) has this:

> With sep=None, read_csv will try to infer the delimiter automatically
>   in some cases by “sniffing”.

How can I access pandas' guess for the delimiter?

I want to read in 10 lines of my file, have pandas guess the delimiter, and start up my GUI with that delimiter already selected. But I don't know how to access what pandas thinks is the delimiter.

Also, is there a way to pass pandas a list of strings to restrict it's guesses to?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looking at the source code, I doubt that it's possible to get the delimiter out of `read_csv`. But `pandas` internally uses the `Sniffer` class from the `csv` module. Here's an example that should get you going:

```
import csv
s = csv.Sniffer()
print s.sniff("a,b,c").delimiter
print s.sniff("a;b;c").delimiter
print s.sniff("a#b#c").delimiter
```

*Output:*

```
,
;
#
```

What remains, is reading the first line from a file and feeding it to the `Sniffer.sniff()` function, but I'll leave that up to you.

Answer (score 2):

The `csv.Sniffer` is the simplest solution, but it doesn't work if you need to use compressed files.
Here's what's working, although it uses a private member, so beware:

```
reader = pd.read_csv('path/to/file.tar.gz', sep=None, engine='python', iterator=True)
sep = reader._engine.data.dialect.delimiter
reader.close()
```

Comment: the output for me is '<pandas.io.parsers.readers.TextFileReader object at 0x0000022E7C362EE0>'

Comment: Pandas has likely changed in these 5 years. And as my answer states, "beware". :) You'll have to figure out what works with the version you're using, if anything.